# Book series with teleporation tech, societal break down, and teenagers

Tags: story-identification

I listened to the audiobooks a few years ago, but cannot find a copy or history of checking it out from my library.

Things I remember about the book/series:

- Teenage, high school, female lead character
- Start of the book is at a jumper(?) party, where bored teens/twenty-somethings go to impromptu parties. These are sorta secret and can be an art. I think the character's first one is at an observatory
- Probably told in 1st person
- Released between 2008-2016, best guess
- House/apartments don't have stairs/elevators/doors, instead you can jump/teleport directly into your home
- Goods were either replicated or transported straight into the home
- Teleporting is actually cloning, but is controlled by a company/agency, who either goes rogue or gets hacked, starts wreaking havoc.
- Finds a boy who has never teleported, thus never having been cloned
- Teleporation can be done in large squares (unless I'm confusing stories...)
- Fights friends and/or a family member who died, but a clone was generated to deceive/kill the main character
- I believe the books were initially released in Australia and were given different names and covers in the USA

Comment: Sounds like a lot of ideas were very similar to Larry Niven's stories about teleportation becoming available on Earth. I remember one story was called "The Last Days of the Permanent Floating Riot Club" and another one was about trying to cover up a murder by exploiting the teleportation technology. But there are many differences also.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I looked through my Niven's collection, as I was reading some of his stuff through there as well. But, I didn't read anything he wrote about a teenage protagonist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Twinmaker** by Sean Williams. 2013. Originally titled **Jump**. Australian author. YA, female protagonist Clair, begins with Clair and her friend Libby using the d-mat booth (teleportation) to attend a Crashlander ball, finding it by The Lucky Jump (random destinations), eventually arriving at Sphinx Observatory.